# save null data in field time mysql

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I need to insert null data if so come. I'm inserting data from EXCEL to my DB. The problem is that I made the table structure and field to allow nulls and also as a default to NULL.

The value is empty and pass all my logical validations but when inserted, left in 21:00:00

PHP :

```
if(!empty($r['tiempo_chip'])){
    $resultados[$i]['tiempo_chip'] = $this->ExcelReader->timeFormat($r['tiempo_chip']);
}else{
    $resultados[$i]['tiempo_chip'] = NULL;
}
```

Data :

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [numero] => 88
        [tiempo_oficial] => 01:10:30
        [tiempo_chip] => 
    )
```

This is stored in the DB 21:00:00

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `resultados` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`numero` int(11) NOT NULL,
`tiempo_oficial` time NOT NULL,
`tiempo_chip` time DEFAULT NULL,
`created` datetime NOT NULL,
`modified` datetime NOT NULL,
)  ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=133 ;
```

Comment: Can you show the `show create table` of your table? It may have an `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: @Kenney edit my post!

Comment: Thanks. So, you do an `INSERT INTO resultados (numero, tiempo_oficial, tiempo_chip, created, modified) VALUES ( 88, '01:10:30', NULL, foo, bar )`, and the `SELECT tiempo_chip FROM resultados WHERE numero=88` says `21:00:00`, is that right?

Comment: If its default null is there any need to insert NULL??? @kenney

Comment: No, there's no need - I just wanted more clarity on the INSERT query/code and the SELECT you did to see what was inserted.

Comment: I think u get the soltuon remove else part and let me know

Comment: I do calculations with the times, so I need to insert this value is null, to avoid interference.